# I have 2 eclipse version 3.8 and neon.. remove 3.8?

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

I have 2 versions of eclipse software running on my ubuntu machine 16.04. But what I want is to remove eclipse 3.8 from my machine.

So what I did is I tried removing the eclipse 3.8 folder from my machine.. But I can't delete it since the folder has some lock icon appeared on it.

So how do I remove 3.8?
I want to remove since in 16.04 eclipse 3.8 is not working properly.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where is the "eclipse 3.8 folder" located?

Comment: @edwinksl Its in my  **/download** location

Comment: Can you do a `ls -l` on the downloads folder in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If your Eclipse installation folder is in your `/Downloads` directory, you can delete the whole Eclipse folder from the command prompt using:

```
sudo rm -rf Eclipse/
```

Of course, you must be located at your Downloads directory. If not, you can use:

```
cd /Downloads
```

And then use the first mentioned command.

Best regards.

Comment: I don't think your asnwer solve the problem. The thing is that Eclipse 3.04 seems to be native and the OP downloaded a new version. If we do it the way you suggest it will remove the latest version